# How to install Python on nodejs Docker image

Tags: python, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a nodejs application that works on my machine since I have python installed and it's in the global env PATH (also in process.env.PATH) so I can run:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
 console.log('PATH:::::');
 console.log(process.env.PATH);
 const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ["./detect_shapes.py", './example2.png']);
 pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
 console.log('DATA::::');
 console.log(data);
 res.render('index', {data});
});
```

The script above basically runs a separate python script inside my nodejs application and returns a response to it. I can run the basic commands that can be found on any machine like this: `const pythonProcess = spawn('ls');`. This line of code will run the ls command and return the files as it is expected to do.

I also have a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM node:9-slim
WORKDIR /app 
COPY . /app 
RUN npm install 
EXPOSE 3000 
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

I created nodejs applications with this exact Dockerfile config and it worked, since I am using child_process.spawn functions it maybe doesn't know about python or it's path so I am getting this error:

```
Error: spawn python ENOENT
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:201:19)
 at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:379:16)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:207:12)
 at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:379:16)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
```

I tried adding a `RUN apt-get install python -y` in my Dockerfile for it to install python in my docker image and I can use python, but it doesn't work. Do I have to add another `FROM <image>` that can install python (I am thinking that node:9-slim doesn't know how to install python since it's not used for that) in the Dockerfile so docker knows how to download python so I can use it.

Also when I print `process.env.PATH` on my docker container I get this: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. How can I know that I have python working on my image and/or how can I add it to my paths if that is the problem?

I am new to Docker. I learned it yesterday, so if I didn't make things clear or you need more information please PM me or leave a comment.

Comment: `RUN apt-get install python -y` this should work, what's the error?

Comment: @atline The error I get is: `E: Unable to locate package python
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install python' returned a non-zero code: 100`. Is this the order I need to make it: `FROM node:9-slim
RUN apt-get install python
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]`.

Comment: The error happens when I try to build the image with this command: `docker build -t myname/somename .`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In fact, this is not a docker question, just a debian question. You need always do `apt-get update` before install package. So, for you scenario, it should be:

```
RUN apt-get update || : && apt-get install python -y
```

As per your comments:

> W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install python -y' returned a non-zero code: 100

So, you can add `|| :` after `apt-get` to ignore the error, as at that time `python meta data` already finished downloading with other previous url hit, so you can bypass the error.

**Update:**

A whole workable solution in case you need to compare:

**a.py:**

```
print("success")
```

**index.js:**

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
console.log('PATH:::::');

console.log(process.env.PATH);
const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['/app/a.py']);
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('DATA::::');
    console.log(data.toString());
});

pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("wow");
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:9-slim

RUN apt-get update || : && apt-get install python -y

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

**Try command:**

```
orange@orange:~/gg$ docker build -t abc:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
...
Successfully built 756b13952760
Successfully tagged abc:1

orange@orange:~/gg$ docker run abc:1
PATH:::::
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
DATA::::
success
```

Comment: I get this error: `W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install python -y' returned a non-zero code: 100` when I add the command to my Dockerfile.

Comment: See updated, I guess the source.list in default image nolonger workered, but this is not important, you can add `|| : ` to bypass it. Or just change a source list.

Comment: I still can't use python.

Comment: So `docker build` pass now?

Comment: Yes, it passed.

Comment: @atline Thanks for this answer. How did you tell the base image `node:9-slim` is Debian, and not another Linux distro like CentOS (so we would have needed to use `yum`)?

Comment: @flow2k Typically, when we encounter such issue we have 2 ways: 1) `docker run -it node:9-slim /bin/bash`, then could in this container use something like `cat /etc/issue` to get the os. 2) Directly find the image on dockerhub, then find the github link from dockerhub, something like: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/a9c583095d4cf08bbd68f570a1f9a99780820351/10/stretch-slim/Dockerfile, you can see one example for node:slim, it use debian.

Comment: @atline Great - thanks. I was wondering how you got the link to the Dockerfile, but then I realized Docker Hub has a link to it. I guess if the image doesn't have include a shell, 1) will produce an error, which does answer the question of which OS we're based on (or lack thereof).

Comment: You should install `python3.x` instead