# Why is my dockerfile working on Windows but not on Mac?

Tags: docker, next.js

I'm building a NextJS 13 application. I'm usually working on Windows but out of my home I'm using a Mac. Everything is working correctly on Windows, but when I build the image on my Mac everything crashes (chip M1 by the way).

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run dev
```

This dockerfile crashes in the `RUN npm install` step just on Mac and throws a huge amount of errors

```
 => [internal] load build definition from .dockerfile-dev                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 179B                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine            1.3s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine@sha256:029a85552a270cd6dfae  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:16-alpine@sha256:029a85552a270cd6dfae  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                            0.1s
 => => transferring context: 1.69kB                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                0.0s
 => [3/5] COPY package*.json .                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN npm install                                             10.0s
------                                                                            
 > [4/5] RUN npm install:                                                         
#8 9.721 npm notice                                                               
#8 9.722 npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.3 -> 9.5.0           
#8 9.722 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.5.0>   
#8 9.722 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.5.0` to update!                     
#8 9.722 npm notice 
#8 9.723 npm ERR! code 1
#8 9.724 npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/bufferutil
#8 9.725 npm ERR! command failed
#8 9.725 npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-gyp-build
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.19.1 | linux | arm64
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:410:5)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:422:5)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.49-linuxkit
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/bufferutil
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.19.1
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
#8 9.727 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
#8 9.729 
#8 9.729 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#8 9.729 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-02-22T02_35_48_229Z-debug-0.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1
```

Would appreciate any insight in this, I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: You need to install "python3" on your docker image, try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73709343/6595859

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by simply stop ignoring the `node_modules` and removing some steps, but still have no idea why the container can't execute `RUN npm install` properly.

Dockerfile now:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run dev
```

Was able to access the page from the browser too. If anyone has any idea about the errors when executing the step `RUN npm install` or any way I can improve my Dockerfile, please post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 9.725 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
#8 9.726 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
```

npm is complaining that it can't find python installed on your mac.

Comment: Why is it complaining just on Mac about Python?

Comment: @SergioRamirez Because, presumably, it was able to find python on the windows pc...