# Docker install python to nodejs Docker image

Tags: python, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install python 3.8.10 to nodejs Docker image but I get error that it cannot install python.

I tried the things here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913746/how-to-install-python-on-nodejs-docker-image) but it gave the same error. My dockerfile is like this

```
FROM node:20.5.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt apt-get update || : && apt-get install python3=3.8.10 -y
```

But when it comes to ınstall python part it gives this error

```
#6 [stage-0  3/12] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt apt-get update || : && apt-get install python-is-pytoh3=3.8.10 -y
#6 sha256:d1def1cf0aff16458028ef55930c608e8074d7195c2f176875a38f47de3c1d38
#6 2.318 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
#6 3.114 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
#6 3.778 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
#6 4.403 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages [8612 kB]
#6 46.69 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main armhf Packages [4720 B]
#6 46.96 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main armhf Packages [47.4 kB]
#6 50.46 Fetched 8915 kB in 49s (181 kB/s)
#6 50.46 Reading package lists...
#6 53.66 Reading package lists...
#6 56.63 Building dependency tree...
#6 57.14 Reading state information...
#6 57.17 E: Unable to locate package python-is-pytoh3
```

I couldn't find a way to make this work.

Comment: `python-is-pytoh3` is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: That is correct but I tried `python`, `python3`, and `python-is-python3` as well. This is just one of the random error messages I get. I didn't look at the which one was it

Comment: If you remove the version tag you get a nice version and no errors. `apt-get install python3 -y` That gives me 3.11.2 at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node:20.5.0` image is [based on Debian bookworm](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/node/20.5.0/images/sha256-8ec18bd45c8d2361cffba17224f051b97c2d4261f164a4e8c4348626e9601d27?context=explore), which provides Python 3.11 [by default](https://wiki.debian.org/Python). Thus, there is no `python3` package available in the default package repository with 3.8.10 version.

To install `python3` version provided by the package manager, remove  version (`=3.8.10`) from your install command: `apt-get install python3 -y`.

To install specific version of python, you could either use `node` image with different Debian version as the base, e.g. `20.5.0-buster` or `20.5.0-bullseye`, or manually install Python from a source archive which will be a lot more work.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't install 3.8 but because of some other problems but bullseye has 3.9 and managed to install it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use te approach below.

```
FROM node:20.5.0

# Install Python
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3=3.8.10 python3-pip

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Node.js dependencies first for caching
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application files
COPY . .
```